# java align an HBox to the bottom left

Tags: java, javafx

I dont want to use a gridpane.

So I have an HBox:

```
HBox fooBar = new HBox();

fooBar.setHeight(100);
fooBar.setWidth(100);
fooBar.setAlignment(pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
```

I gave it a color in css.

I include it into my scene and for some reason the box stays stuck on the bottom left corner. Is there any way to position it?

I forgot to mention: this hbox is the child of another hbox where I didnt define any position or dimension.

Comment: You have to define position in parent not in child. In parent HBox set aligment and then add this box like child, and this box will be in this position.

Comment: If you want to see the box in the bottom-left go the scene, you have to give the pos.BOTTOM-LEFT to the box's parent

Answer (score 1):

Hbox is a component which determine position own children. If you want change position you should change alignment property in parent. It impact for all children. You couldn't change position for one child. All children have to be obedient.
You can use Pane for absolute positioning.
[image]

[image]